# How can I simply retrieve the absolute path of the current script (multi OS solution)?

Tags: shell

I am looking for a simple solution to retrieve the absolute path of the current script. It needs to be platform independent (I want it to work on linux, freebsd, macos and without bash).

- "readlink -f $0" works on linux but not on freebsd and macos: readlink
  doesn't have the "-f" option.
- "realpath $0" works on freebsd and linux but not on macos: I don't have this command.

EDIT : 
Solution for retrieve the path of the repository of the script :

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )" (source : [Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in#comment3818043_246128) )

Comment: FYI, `realpath` is available on Debian and Ubuntu in the `realpath` package.

Comment: What is "the absolute path"?  If /tmp/foo and /tmp/bar are (hard) links to the same file, which one is the absolute path?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And AFAIK there is no portable way to get symlink destination for a file, only the directory as you have already found. Also, that should be `pwd -P` there.

Comment: Note that the solution you added to your question, `DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"` does _not_ tell you where your script file truly lives if it was invoked via a _symlink_ - it only tells you where the _symlink_ lives (and using `pwd -P` would then resolve to the symlink directory's true path, but that is not the same).

Comment: Closely related (asks for the script's _directory_ path): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832037/how-to-get-script-directory-in-posix-sh

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/bin/sh

self=$(
    self=${0}
    while [ -L "${self}" ]
    do
        cd "${self%/*}"
        self=$(readlink "${self}")
    done
    cd "${self%/*}"
    echo "$(pwd -P)/${self##*/}"
)

echo "${self}"
```

It's «mostly portable». Pattern substitution and `pwd -P` is POSIX, and the latter is usually a shell built-in. `readlink` is pretty common but it's not in POSIX.

And I don't think there is a simpler mostly-portable way. If you really need something like that, I'd suggest you rather try to get *realpath* installed on all your systems.

Answer (score 1):

For zsh scripts, FWIW:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
fullpath=$0:A
```